# Blender 2.6: Select object by name through Python

Tags: python, blender, bpy

How do you select objects by name through Python in Blender 2.6?

In **2.4-2.5**, one could simply use:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_name("OBJECT")
```

... but this has been discontinued in **2.6**, to be replaced by what?

---

In **2.6**, one can get the currently selected objects like so...

```
bpy.context.selected_objects
```

And there's a way to set the scene's active object...

```
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects["OBJECT"]
```

And one can also select via *operations*, like `select_all()` or `select_by_type()`...

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="TOGGLE")
```

But I can't find a way to select simply by *name.*

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
bpy.data.objects['OBJECT'].select = True
```

---

Selection data is contained within the individual objects. You can read *and* write them as shown. In a slightly more readable form:

```
object = bpy.data.objects['OBJECT']
object.select = True
```

Answer (score 15):

`bpy.ops.object.select_name()` has been replaced by `bpy.ops.object.select_pattern()` (around 2.62, I think?), which is a more powerful version (it can select an exact name, but also use patterns with wildcards, be case-insensitive, etc.):

```
bpy.ops.object.select_pattern(pattern="Cube")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import bpy

def returnObjectByName (passedName= ""):
    r = None
    obs = bpy.data.objects
    for ob in obs:
        if ob.name == passedName:
            r = ob
    return r

obs = bpy.data.objects

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for ob in obs:
    print (ob.name)
    myObj = returnObjectByName(ob.name)
    if myObj != None:
        print (dir(myObj))
        myObj.selected = True
        myObj.location[2] = 10
        myObj.selected = False
```

Not my code, not guaranteed to work.

[Source](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?187565-bpy-ops-object-select_name-doesn-t-work&p=1630103&viewfull=1#post1630103)

Comment: Aha! Each object has it's own selected property! Thanks, I'll put this into a readable answer.